# Error while trying to load json file into external table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-serde

Data looks like:

> {"custId":1185972,"movieId":null,"genreId":null,"time":"2012-07-01:00:00:07","recommended":null,"activity":8}

The query i am running is:

```
add jar /home/student/hive-0.11.0-bin/lib/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE movie_json 
( custId INT, movieId INT, genreId INT, 
time STRING, recommended STRING, activity INT, rating INT, price FLOAT ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
LOCATION '/user/oracle/movie/';
```

The error encountered is:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: byteTypeInfo  at
>   org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.primitive.TypeEntryShim.(TypeEntryShim.java:27)
>     at
>   org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.primitive.JavaStringJsonObjectInspector.(JavaStringJsonObjectInspector.java:14)
>     at
>   org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.JsonObjectInspectorFactory.(JsonObjectInspectorFactory.java:196)
>     at org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe.initialize(JsonSerDe.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:268)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:261)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:587)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:576)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3776)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:256)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:144)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1355)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1139)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:945)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156) FAILED: Execution
>   Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

I used various JsonSerder jars but getting the same error. Please help me.

Comment: There are 8 table fields whereas there are only 6 keys in your JSON. The data and the fields must match for jsonserde to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `JsonSerDe` you are using . Bu here this `JsonSerDe`you can use.

[Hive-JSON-Serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)

```
hive> add jar /User/User1/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
Added [/User/User1/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/User/User1/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar]
hive>CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE movie_json ( custId INT, movieId INT, genreId INT, time STRING, recommended STRING, activity INT, rating INT, price FLOAT ) ROW FORMAT SERDE'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION'/user/oracle/movie/';
OK
Time taken: 0.097 seconds
```

you can build Jar by using

```
C:\Users\User1\Downloads\Hive-JSON-Serde-develop\Hive-JSON-Serde-develop>mvn -Phdp23 clean package.
-Phdp23 is hdp2.3 it should be replaced with your hadoop version.
```

You can also use inbuilt `jsonserde` [get_json_object](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object) [json_tuple](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-json_tuple)If you are looking for example how to use inbuilt `jsonserde` look at this example 
[Example](http://thornydev.blogspot.in/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html).

I will suggest validate your `Json` [Validate JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)